# Why does my manifest.json trigger a lengthly review due to Broad Host Permissions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

The chrome webstore flags my extension as having "Broad Host Permissions", but I cannot figure out what in my manifest.json is causing this result.

```
{
    "name": "AudioEye Smart Remediation Builder",
    "description": "Solve any issue of accessibility without writing code. Select elements, apply changes, and fix the web.",
    "devtools_page": "src/main.html",
    "version": "1.31.0",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://myother.website.com/scripts/loader.js https://myotherother.website.com/somescript.js; object-src 'self'",
    "author": "AudioEye",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "src/background.bundle.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/ae16.png",
            "48": "icons/ae48.png",
            "128": "icons/ae128.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "src/popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://my.website.com/*"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": true,
            "js": [
                "src/installDefinition.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [
            "*://my.website.com/*"
        ]
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/ae16.png",
        "48": "icons/ae48.png",
        "128": "icons/ae128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "optional_permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "webNavigation",
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "contextMenus"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "src/inspected-window.bundle.js",
        "src/smart-remediation-metadata.js"
    ]
}
```

I only use a broad match in the optional_permissions object, which gives the user explicit ability to allow/deny the permissions on each page they visit.

Why does my extension require a two week review due to broad host permissions?

Comment: The thing is, the chrome's web store review process is a complete joke, and most of the reviewers aren't programmers so do as I do: be pleasantly surprised every time they do something right. On a serious note though, there's nothing you can do code-wise, as your manifest.json is fine. Provided you didn't make a blunder like replacing `.com` with `.*` in the real json.

Comment: OTOH I see your CSP allows external scripts, which is a no-no on the web store - either it'll be soon completely forbidden or maybe it already is.